# css3 sync multiple element animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have 2 element, one on top of the other and they both animate. Despite using the same keyframe rule and animation properties, the elements are out of sync on the first loop but are in sync after the first loop. WHY?!

The markup:

```
<div class="small xfade">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="big xfade">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

The css:

```
@keyframes xfade {
    0%   { opacity:1; }
    17%  { opacity:1; }
    25%  { opacity:0; }
    92%  { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

.xfade span {
    animation-name: xfade;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 8s;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/3KNa9/)

**EDIT** In my real-world implementation, the "small" elements are translucent, so the ones underneath are visible at the start of the animation. I thought setting `opacity: 0;` on all of small's children would solve this (since the keyframe rule brings it back to 1 as soon as the animation kicks in); alas no. This issue also mysteriously solves itself after the first loop.

Any tips for that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you noticed you have a syntax error ?  .xfade.big span:nth-of-type(1) {
 background: #33000;
}

Comment: Updated fiddle. Is this you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3KNa9/1/

Comment: @vals no, but that wasn't actually causing a problem.

Comment: @SurjithSM, YES! What did you do? I just ran a diff and the only differences it highlighted were hex-code changes.

Comment: @jacob Yes. I just changed the color code, as vals mentioned, one of the color code is wrong, so first and second color is same. So it feels like the animation is not working.

Comment: @jacob I added it as an answer

Comment: @SurjithSM weird, when i added the missing `0` back to the hex-code it still wasn't working.

Comment: @jacob Change color code for big span `3` and `4`

Comment: @vals i stand corrected. thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vals mentioned, one of the color code you have given is wrong, so first and second color is same. So it feels like the animation is not working as it is same color. (But actually its working)

So, I changed the color code and working fine.

```
.xfade.big span:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: #0300FF;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3KNa9/1/)**